# Javascript mathjs-Module, Increment Matrix

Tags: javascript, math, matrix, increment

How can i increment one value of my matrix (using the math module; https://mathjs.org/)? The only way, I came up with, was the following (and this can't be the correct/easiest solution...):

```
matrix = math.ones(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
//starting matrix: [[[[[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]]], [[[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]]]], [[[[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]]], [[[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]]]]]

matrix = math.subset(matrix, math.index(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), math.add(math.subset(matrix, math.index(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 1));
console.log(math.print('$x', {x: matrix}));
//output: [[[[[2, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]]], [[[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]]]], [[[[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]]], [[[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]]]]]
```

Comment: What is "the math module"?  Can you link to it?  Is it an npm module?  Are you talking about the [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) API?

Comment: @zero298 looks like it is this https://mathjs.org/ :EDIT yup it is this library checked Docs and found same functions

Comment: could you please give a clearer example of what you are trying to do? can we get a starting point and then 1st and or 2nd iteration through?

Comment: Added the starting matrix.
Actually I need to add/subtract 1 (ergo increment/decrement) to/from a certain element in the matrix (provided example would be: matrix[0,0,0,0,0] ++)